# How to create an infinity/tunnel perspective effect with one object/layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Im sorry if the title is somehow misleading or false, but i dont know how to express it accurately.

Lets say you have a picture of a old railway. After a few meters the railway changes its direction, but the first part or the bottom of the picture goes straigt. Now i want to take this part of the straight forward goind railway, erase the rest and paste the straight railway behind the first, but smaller. All in all i want to create an effect like a tunnel, like the railway continues into infinity. Somehow like this: http://hd.wallpaperswide.com/thumbs/railway_tunnel-t2.jpg

I hope you know what i mean and hopefully this isnt a totally dumb question, if so, im sorry.

Hope the screenshot helps you understand. [image]

Comment: The term you are looking for is "vanishing point" and I'm not too sure what you are asking, because it seems like you've pretty much got the gist.  What have you tried so far and what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you tried the **Vanishing Point** filter?

Comment: I cuted out a part of a picture and pasted it multiple times behind the original. I made the paste parts smaller and aligned so it looks fluent. The problem is, around the railway is nature or trees. The vegetation includes many details, making it look fluent is almost impossible. There are lots of trees/leafs, which interfere with each other. I cant post a screenshot now, because i am not at home, its hard to explain for me. I read somewhere there is a modifier in Photoshop that creates this tunnel effect. Maybe that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

My simple answer is related to BLEND tool in Adobe Illustrator:

You can create a start shape and end shape and use the blend tool to create all other shape in between of these two:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can color the shapes differently - blend tool will change hues of constructed shapes.

You can use perspective tool too, but for your task it is a little bit too much.